# What does build with cl mean for a c++ program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com-interop

the file comclient.cpp here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645738(v=vs.71).aspx
says build with cl. what does that mean?

and also what type of project should I create n vc++? win32, console?

Comment: cl.exe is Microsoft's C/C++ compiler. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7c9wdw(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its the commandline compiler for visual studio for visualc++. Visual studio itself is just a mere IDE to help you code easier. Just like Devcpp has gcc and g++ as its compilers.

Comment: and also what type of project should I create n vc++? win32, console?

Comment: well the article tells you to build with cl so thats what you should do. Unfortunately its a commandline compiler so you have to open tools menu => visual studio command prompt. Then change directory to folder where COMClient.cpp file is found and type  cl COMClient.cpp(I removed visualstudio so am not too sure if the visual studio command prompt is found on the tools menu but it is there somewhere)